# Transformation from cartesian to polar Coordinates of Vector Field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

This is fairly low-level, still I would like to get a verification:

I vector field $$\mathbf{F}=F_x \hat{e_x} + F_y \hat{e_y} = F_r \hat{e_r} + F_{\phi} \hat{e_\phi}$$ given in cartesian coordinates, and want to transform it to polar coordinates.

I was reading [Vector fields in cylindrical and spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) and [Del in cylindrical and spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) at wikipedia aswell as entries on that topic here, still I am not sure whether this is correct:

$$F_r=\frac{x\cdot F_x + y\cdot F_y}{r}\\$$
$$F_{\phi}=\frac{-y\cdot F_x + x\cdot F_y}{r}\\$$

> 1) Could you please verify/falsify,
>
> 2) Provide me a reference for how to derive this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right ! See example 1, p. 3 in this [pdf](http://www.phy.iitb.ac.in/dkg/public_html/PH-102/calculus.pdf).

Comment: Ohh right, I remember again now. Thanks alot!!

Comment: This PDF cannot be found on the server

Comment: @Qbyte: try now.

Comment: It's broken again.